# Django & Celery using manage.py

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, djcelery

I'm using Django 1.6 and Celery 3.1.1

Back when the django-celery app was required I didn't seem to have a problem. Using the [new method](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) of running celery, I can get it to work, but I can't seem to get celerycam working.

If try to run `./manage.py celeryd -B -E` I get the following error:

> consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://guest@127.0.0.1:5672//: [Errno 111]
>   Connection refused.

It is completely ignoring my BROKER_URL in settings.py. I've set up the celery.py file described in [the docs](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) and it all seems to work.

Now I want to run celerycam, which as I understand does require django-celery still. When I try to run celerycam (`./manage.py celerycam`) I get the following error:

> socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

I assume this is the same reason I get the error trying to call celeryd from manage.py - because it is not reading my settings.py file. Anyone know how I can get django-celery to read my `BROKER_URL` setting?

Answer (score 4):

As often happens, the act of typing out my project led to my solution.

Adding the following fixed my issue:

```
import djcelery
djcelery.setup_loader()
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't those lines require django-celery again, which is already discouraged since celery 3.1+?